# How to check existence of a JAR file and a specific file inside JAR?

Tags: java

Assume the file name is in this URL:

```
URL file = new URL("jar:file:/path/to/foo.jar!/META-INF/file.txt");
```

This operation leads to `IOException` if there is no `foo.jar` or there is no `file.txt` inside the existing jar:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(file, /* some other file */);
```

Is it possible to validate file existence without exception catching?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [java.util.jar.JarFile class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html), and use the [getJarEntry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html#getJarEntry-java.lang.String-) method to see if the file exists.

```
JarFile jar = new JarFile("foo.jar");
JarEntry entry = jar.getJarEntry("META-INF/file.txt");
if (entry != null) {
    // META-INF/file.txt exists in foo.jar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can examine the CLASSPATH and search for the jar yourself. Then you can inspect the jar yourself. I guess it will not be faster than your way, nor will it be more easy to understand, so why do you want to avoid the Exception?

I don't see something wrong in using the exception.

Comment: Exceptions have too many causes. Catching `java.io.IOException` will convert every I/O problem to the signal of `file.txt` absence in JAR. Not a reasonable judgement, huh?

Comment: Yes, I agree if you can handle absence of file.txt in the jar, and other jar-problems differently, it is fine to make a difference.